# mod_ssl RPM conflict

Tags: httpd, rpm, mod-ssl

I build Apache httpd into an RPM using these sites:

- http://erikwebb.net/blog/compile-and-install-apache-24-red-hat-enterprise-linux-rhel-6-or-centos-6
- http://ramblin-dude.blogspot.com/2013/04/compiling-rpm-for-httpd-on-rhel-57.html

I was successful at building apr* and httpd*. However, when I try to install httpd using

```
rpm -Uvh httpd-devel-2.2.25-1.x86_64.rpm httpd-2.2.25-1.x86_64.rpm mod_ssl-2.2.25-1.x86_64.rpm
```

I get the following error:

> package mod_ssl-2.2.3-82.el5_9.x86_64 (which is newer than
>   mod_ssl-2.2.25-1.x86_64) is already installed.

I have httpd 2.2.3-82 installed. Do I need to remove it first? Seems counterintuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link points to a guide for installing the current stable apache version - 2.4.
The second link refers to apache version 2.2.
These are not arbitrarily interchangeable; for starters, they are markedly different in both internals and configuration.

But most importantly, each apache version and package needs to be built with the same version of apr/apxs in order to be able to use modules.
This is documented profusely in the apache httpd installation instructions.

I strongly suggest building and installing the latest stable apache version (at the time of writing, 2.4.6) as it has been GA for over a year.

And, as is obvious from your post, remove the old version of apache and mod_ssl before installing this one.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know there were so many different changes. Will try 2.4.6.

Comment: BE SURE to carefully read the changelog for 2.2 -> 2.4; your 2.x configuration will most likely not work without some alteration.

Comment: Got it. I now understand this won't be an easy task. I will read carefully.